# "cannot find symbol method setOnDismissListener(<anonymous OnDismissListener>)"

Tags: java, android, dialog, listener, dialogfragment

So, I try to set an `OnDismissListener` on a dialog thing.

```
Datepicker dialog = new Datepicker(v);
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface Dialog) {
                        mGoogleMap.clear();
                        setMap(mGoogleMap);
                    }

                });
```

But it says

```
"Cannot resolve method 'setOnDismissListener(anonymous android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener)'"
```

The `Datepicker` class extends `DialogFragment`, so it should have the `setOnDismissListener` method?

I've imported `android.content.DialogInterface'. Is it confused on the`new DialogInterface.onDismissListener()` for some reason?

Edit: Someone asked for some of the Datepicker code. So here's the constructor and stuff. Let me know if you need anything else.

```
public class Datepicker extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    EditText txtDate;
    String strdate;
    public Datepicker(View v){
        txtDate = (EditText)v;
    }
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        SimpleDateFormat simpleformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        strdate = simpleformat.format(c.getTime());
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Datepicker` class extends `DialogFragment`, so it should have the `setOnDismissListener` method? - From where and how did you come to this statement? There is no such method called `setOnDismissListener` in `DialogFragment`

Comment: Huh. Maybe that's where I went wrong?

The Android API says "Note: DialogFragment own the Dialog.setOnCancelListener and Dialog.setOnDismissListener callbacks. You must not set them yourself. To find out about these events, override onCancel(DialogInterface) and onDismiss(DialogInterface)." but I don't know what that means. What can I do?

Comment: The API is says it very clearly, you shoud not do `setOnCancelListener` or `setOnDismissListener` , just overrride `onCancel` or `onDismiss` directly in your class extending `DialogFragment` (and do what you want to do when the dialog is cancelled/dismissed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to resolve this issue with a help of interface

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerListener{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

.........

     //Initialise or create your dialog like this
      DatePicker dialog = new DatePicker(v,this);
}

@Override
    public void onDatePickerDismissed() {
         //Here You receive the dialog dissmiss listner
                        mGoogleMap.clear();
                        setMap(mGoogleMap);
    }
}
```

Create  a interface class like

```
public interface DatePickerListener {

    public void onDatePickerDismissed();
}
```

Change you dialog picker like this

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class DatePicker extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    EditText txtDate;
    String strdate;
    DatePickerListener datePickerListener;
    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public DatePicker(View v, DatePickerListener _datePickerListener){
        txtDate = (EditText)v;
        this.datePickerListener = _datePickerListener;
    }

    public DatePicker() {

    }

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        SimpleDateFormat simpleformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        strdate = simpleformat.format(c.getTime());
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        datePickerListener.onDatePickerDismissed();
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you :)